# Is there a way to store int value in object GKScore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I am trying to integrate Gamecenter to my app, but I cant seem to get it to work:

```
- (void) reportScore {
GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"High_Scores_LeaderBoard"];

[GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

}

I use the above method to report the score to gamecenter. However I stored my score in this int:

```
extern int g_nScore;
```

is there a way for me to store g_nScore as a GKScore so that I can run the above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GKScore has a "`value`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKScore/value), which is a "`int64_t`".

Why not set the "`.value`" property of your "`score`" object to "`g_nScore`"?